# NVM repositorios globales

Tags: npm, nvm

Buenas compañeros una duda. Si tengo instalado mvm a cada versión de node debo asignarle el prefijo al repositorio global donde tengo mis paquetes guardados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De lo que he comprobado en cada versión de node de nvm se guardan por separado sus librerias globales.